# SMPP SubmitMessage destroying some character like @ ^ _ i use SMSCRelay Component

Tags: delphi, sms, smpp

i have SMSCRelay ActiveX component used in Delphi 2010 ,the problem when i send messages includes some characters like ( @ ^ _ ) i got message with question marks instead of these characters .

My code and my dangerous solution :(

```
if  MessageIsArabic  then
              MsgEncoding :=  etUCS2Text
                else
              MsgEncoding :=  et7bitText;


MessageSendResult := FSMPPConnection.SubmitMessageEx(Mobile,1,1,SenderOrigTon,OrigNpi,Msg,MsgEncoding,FPartUDH,m_ReqReport,now,now+1,'','',ProtID,OutMessageID );
```

my old solution is check if message includes these characters set encoding to etUCS2Text But I Find out the difference between the provider report and our report in counting.

```
 if  MessageArabic  then
              MsgEncoding :=  etUCS2Text
              else
                begin 
                  MsgEncoding :=  et7bitText ;
                  if pos('@',FInMessage.OutMessage)>0 then MsgEncoding := etUCS2Text ;
                  if pos('#',FInMessage.OutMessage)>0 then MsgEncoding := etUCS2Text ;
                  if pos('^',FInMessage.OutMessage)>0 then MsgEncoding := etUCS2Text ;
                  if pos('_',FInMessage.OutMessage)>0 then MsgEncoding := etUCS2Text ;
                end;
```

the problem in english messages when includes these characters

the encodings a vailable in component

```
et7bitText
et8bitHexadecimal
etUCS2Text
etISO88591
etISO88595
etISO88598
etASCIIText
etWAPPushOrMMS
```

please any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't know this  component, but have you tried etASCIIText for english texts? I'd assume it could perform conversion from ASCII-7 to native GSM 7bit alphabet GSM 3.38 (instead of control chars is uses special chars, e.g. ord('@') = 0x00). If it will not help, then you probably could use et7bitText and do the conversion ASCII->GSM 3.38 yourself

Comment: i used etISO88591 and works fine now, but i don't if i'll face the report deference between provider and us.